# MVC Two DropdownListFor bound to same item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am attempting a standard paging functionality for a grid where the user can pick the number of items per page.  I have a page size shown at both the top and the bottom.  Only the top one works.  The second one posts but doesn't change the value of the underlying model.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.PageSize, Model.Sizes, new {onchange = "this.form.submit();"})

@Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.PageSize, Model.Sizes, new { id="pageSize2", name="pageSize2", onchange = "this.form.submit();"})
```

Comment: you can't change the id on a for helper.  If you look at the source on the page the id for both will be PageSize which is probably where you issue is coming from.  I would recommend adding a second parameter to your model to tie the second drop down to

Comment: How do I know which one of the drop downs caused the submission?

Comment: we use ajax calls for sending most of our data back which would give you more control.  For a submit you could set a hidden field on the form and set it to the drop down name on change.  Then look at the form.collection or Request.Form to see what the value of that field is